# Error while running code

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex

Below my code that I am trying to run. I am getting multiple errors, such as `! Undefined control sequence. \input pictex\magnification` and `` ! I can't find file `pictex=1200'.<to be read again>\relax \input pictex\magnification=\magstep1 ``.

Do I need to download additional packages or is there an error in the code (I program in c++ and python but not familiar with Tex)? I want to output the data to a PDF file.

```
\input pictex\magnification=\magstep1\nopagenumbers
\centerline {
\beginpicture
\setcoordinatesystem units <0.45 truein, 1.5 truein>
\setplotarea x from -5 to 5, y from  0 to 1.0
\axis bottom
ticks numbered from -5 to 5 by 1
/
\plot "Normal.txt"
\plot -5.2 0 -5.1 0 -5.1 1  -5.2 1 /
\put {0} [cr] at -5.3 0
\put {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$} [cr] at -5.3 1
\put {\sl Standard Normal Histogram} at 0 1.2
\sethistograms
\plot "HistogramData.txt"
\endpicture}\vfill\end
```

Comment: I don't have an error at `\input pictex\magnification`, but on `\frac`. Do you typeset with `pdftex`? `\frac` isn't a TeX control sequence. What if you replace `\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}` by `1\over\sqrt{2\pi}`? If this isn't suffisant, can you provide the content of files "Normal.txt" and "HistogramData.txt"?

Comment: @quark67 how are you compiling the file?

Comment: With `pdftex name.tex` where name.tex is the name of the file with the above code.

Comment: My compile error `restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Histogram.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.tex)
(./Normal.txt)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \frac 
<argument> $\frac 
{1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}$
\!setputobject ...->\setbox \!putobject =\hbox {#1
 }\!ht =\ht \!putobject \!d...
\put #1#2 at #3 #4 ->\!setputobject {#1}{#2}
 \!xpos =\!M {#3}\!xunit \!ypos =...
<argument> ...{1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}$} [cr] at -5.3 1 
\put {\sl Standard Normal ..
\centerline #1->\line {\hss #1
 \hss }
l.16 \endpicture}
  \vfill\end
? `

Comment: The error is here: `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \frac  <argument> $\frac`. As stated before, replace the undefined `\frac{...}{...}` with `\over`, using it's syntax (`1\over\sqrt{2\pi}`). The command `\frac` is for LaTeX, not TeX.

Comment: If this resolve your issue, I can write an answer.

Comment: @quark67 Resolved!

Answer (score 2):

You obtain this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \frac  <argument> $\frac
```

The error is that `\frac{}{}` isn't a control sequence understood by TeX. For fractions, use the `\over` TeX primitive.

So replace the line

```tex
\put {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$} [cr] at -5.3 1
```

by

```tex
\put {$1\over\sqrt{2\pi}$} [cr] at -5.3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it help, but here is an example of the same code using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
\draw[->] (-5.2,0) -- (5.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.0) node[above] {$y$};
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5} {
  \draw (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
}
\node at (-5.3,0) {0};
\node at (-5.3,1) {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$};
\node at (0,1.2) {\sl Standard Normal Histogram};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```